# Python openpyxl to automate entire column in excel

Tags: python, pandas, openpyxl

```py
import openpyxl
i=2
workbook= openpyxl.load_workbook()
sheet = workbook.active
for i, cellObj in enumerate (sheet['I'],2):
  cellObj.value = '=IF(ISNUMBER(A2)*(A2<>0),A2,IF(ISNUMBER(F2)*(F2<>0),F2,IF(ISBLANK(A2)*ISBLANK(F2)*ISBLANK(H2),0,H2)))'
workbook.save()
```

Using openpxl, I tried to apply formula to entire column 'I' its not working as per the formula, I wanted formula to start from I2 but its start from I1 and wrong output as well.

I have attached a screenshot.

[image: output result in column I].

Can someone please correct the code?

Output of `print(list(enumerate(sheet['I'])))`:

[image: Output]

Comment: Could you share the result of `print(list(enumerate(sheet['I'])))`?

Comment: Hello ibarrond, thank you for the reply, I have attached result of print(list(enumerate(sheet['I']))) above. mentioned as Output.

Comment: You are iterating column I so the first cell in will be in row 1, there is nothing in your code that will skip the first row. The enumerate you have does nothing. If you are going to do it that way then you need to continue on the first row. Otherwise the code is writing your formula as is to column I. Be aware the formula references will all be the same i.e. to row 2 if you want these to change for each row you'll need to update each time before writing to the cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd probably be better off to do it this way, auto skip row 1 by starting the iteration at row 2 and update the formula using the cell row number.

```
import openpyxl

excelfile = 'foo.xlsx'
workbook= openpyxl.load_workbook(excelfile)
sheet = workbook.active

mr = sheet.max_row  # Last row to add formula to 
for row in sheet.iter_rows(min_col=9, max_col=9, min_row=2, max_row=mr):
    for cell in row:
        cr = cell.row  # Get the current row number to use in formula
        cell.value = f'=IF(ISNUMBER(A{cr})*(A{cr} <> 0), A{cr}, IF(ISNUMBER(F{cr})*(F{cr} <> 0), F{cr}, IF(ISBLANK(A{cr})*ISBLANK(F{cr})*ISBLANK(H{cr}), 0, H{cr})))'

workbook.save(excelfile)
```

Comment: Thank you you so much moken, now it is working from row 2 and has perfect output.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the from and to row numbers, then you can use it like this:

```py
from openpyxl import load_workbook
wb = load_workbook(filename="/content/sample_data/Book1.xlsx")
ws = wb.active
from_row = 2
to_row = 4
for i in range(from_row, to_row+1):
  ws[f"C{i}"] = f'=_xlfn.CONCAT(A{i}, "_", B{i})'
wb.save("/content/sample_data/formula.xlsx")
```

Input (Book1.xlsx):

[image]

Output (formula.xlsx):

[image]

I don't have your data, so I did not test the following formula; but your formula can be translated to format string as:

```py
for i in range(from_row, to_row+1):
  ws[f"I{i}"] = f'=IF(ISNUMBER(A{i})*(A{i}<>0),A{i},IF(ISNUMBER(F{i})*(F{i}<>0),F{i},IF(ISBLANK(A{i})*ISBLANK(F{i})*ISBLANK(H{i}),0,H{i})))'
```

It formats the formula as:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(A2)*(A2<>0),A2,IF(ISNUMBER(F2)*(F2<>0),F2,IF(ISBLANK(A2)*ISBLANK(F2)*ISBLANK(H2),0,H2)))

=IF(ISNUMBER(A3)*(A3<>0),A3,IF(ISNUMBER(F3)*(F3<>0),F3,IF(ISBLANK(A3)*ISBLANK(F3)*ISBLANK(H3),0,H3)))

=IF(ISNUMBER(A4)*(A4<>0),A4,IF(ISNUMBER(F4)*(F4<>0),F4,IF(ISBLANK(A4)*ISBLANK(F4)*ISBLANK(H4),0,H4)))
```

Comment: Thank you Azhar Khan, for the solution.